# Sequential execution of cli commands

Tags: python, postgresql, subprocess, backup, pg-dump

I am writing a Python script to automate.To be precise trying to implement using subprocess module.

sp=subprocess.Popen("pg_dump -d mydb -U postgres -f d:\BackUp\Backup.sql,shell='True',stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

But it should be implemented in the this path(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin).

How to change the env path variable to the mentioned path only for the particular subprocess without changing path for the entire script.

NOT WORKING....`sp = subprocess.Popen("pg_dump -d mydb -U postgres -f d:\BackUp\Backup.sql,shell='True',stdout=subprocess.PIPEe,cwd="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin")`

NOT WORKING....`import subprocess, os my_env = os.environ.copy() my_env["PATH"] = "/usr/sbin:/sbin:" + my_env["PATH"] subprocess.Popen(my_command, env=my_env)`

Comment: please provide more information like which tool you are using? you can use shell scripting, NodeJs for required task

Comment: How do you know it didn't work?  The "output" you show looks just like the command prompt, which is what you would see if it had worked.

Comment: @jjanes If it worked a backup file must have been created in the path mentioned

Comment: @akshay I have elaborated my question.

Comment: You should add a python tag if your question is about how to do something in python.  Anyway, `os.chdir()` is how you change directories in python.

Comment: @jjanes I don't want to change the path for the entire script...it should be changed only for that particular subprocess